# How to get field in an array or null with jq?

Tags: jq

If you run the below you'll see I get only the first item in the array with the error of not being able to iterate over null. I can't seem to figure out how to allow the area to be null if `.in` or `.in.id` is null. Using `?` makes the error go away but it's still only the first item

```
echo '[{"a":1, "in": [{"id":2}] },{"a":4}]' | jq '.[] | {section:.a, area_or_null:.in[].id}'
{
  "id": 1,
  "id_or_null": 2
}
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suppression operator returns the special value `empty` in case of error. `empty` is not part of the result. But you can provide an alternative value with the [`//` alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Alternativeoperator://):

```
.[] | {section:.a, area_or_null:(.in[]?.id//null)}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "section": 1,
  "area_or_null": 2
}
{
  "section": 4,
  "area_or_null": null
}
```